# How to have Resharper leave some code as is?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

I have this line in my visual studio 2019 c# code:

```
using static My.Globals;
```

When using "Cleanup Code", the word static is removed and the line is changed into

```
using My.Globals;
```

What can I do to have Resharper/Cleanup code leave that line as is?

New finding:
At Jetbrains, I find this has been a long standing issue/bug.
I still wonder if there is at least a work-around, like disabling Resharper for only this line...

Comment: If it performs a change like this. it is definitely a bug, try reporting it to their feedback site please

Comment: You can disable the specific warnings

Comment: Pavel: But then it would still remove the "static", would it not?

Comment: Does removing the static cause a compile error?

Comment: yes, it does cause a compile error.